# Can I have two separate web servers/application servers accessing the same database, mysql

Tags: apache, tomcat, phpmyadmin, webserver

I have apache tomcat application server and wamp(apache) installed in my machine(localhost). My php application runs on wamp, and the webservices(SOAP) are based on java, which need to make changes to the mysql database. Is it possible for both wamp/Apache(port 80) and Java services/Tomcat(port 8888) to access the same mysql database..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! Generally you can have multiple programs access a database, even the same database and at the same time. Fundamentally at the database level, it doesn't care where the incoming connections are from, you can have as many and as often as you like (up to the resource limits that are configured or the capability of the server to keep up). Just another great thing about databases.